# Function that return the lines where test is true for first time, then second time, then third time etc

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Title is vague. I will try to provide example.

I column where there are values, it is organized like in the screencap.
[Example of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TberG.png)

I need a function I can drag down and that will return the line where the test (value = A) is true for the first time then true for the second time, and so on.

In my example, if I search for "A", it should return 1 then 2 then 3 then 6 then 12 and then 0 or N/A or an error.

Edit : Thanks to Gary's Student for a function that perfectly matched my needs.

BR,
a1a1a1a1

Answer (score 0):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/($A$1:$A$13="A"), ROW(1:1)),"")
```

and copy downward:

[image]